# Problem with suspend function in Kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am following this video to use Kotlin coroutine : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOHK_w09pVA&t=1326s
, at 9:30 in the video.
But when I write the similar code, it doesn't behave like i expected:

**WalletDao.kt**

```
interface WalletDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wallet LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getFirstWallet(): Wallet
}
```

**Repository.kt**

```
class Repository private constructor(appContext: Context) {
    private val appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext)
//current wallet
    private var _currentWallet : MutableLiveData<Wallet> = MutableLiveData()
    var currentWallet : LiveData<Wallet> = _currentWallet
    suspend fun initFirstWallet()
    {
        val fW = withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        {
            appDatabase.walletDao.getFirstWallet()
        }
        _currentWallet.value = fW
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel()
{
    var currentWallet: LiveData<Wallet> = repository.currentWallet
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.initFirstWallet()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
    private fun registerObservers() {
        ...
       
        viewModel.currentWallet.observe(this)
        {
            if (it != null) {
                binding.walletName.text = it.name
                binding.walletBalance.text = it.amount.toString()
                viewModel.onCurrentWalletChange()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code in MainActivity, sometimes the lambda of viewModel.currentWallet get called and the name of the current wallet is dislpayed, **BUT** most of the time it doesn't get called.
I have change the code to the folloiwing but not thing has changed:

**Repository.kt**

```
class Repository private constructor(appContext: Context) {
    suspend fun initFirstWallet()
    {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        {
            _currentWallet.postValue(appDatabase.walletDao.getFirstWallet())
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the above code??? Thank you very much!

Comment: You do not have to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in repository i think `Room` will handle it for you. Remove and try it with just `_currentWallet.postValue(appDatabase.walletDao.getFirstWallet())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use coroutines for this.

WalletDao.kt

```
interface WalletDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wallet LIMIT 1")
    fun getFirstWallet(): LiveData<Wallet>
}
```

Repository.kt

```
class Repository private constructor(appContext: Context) {
    private val appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext)

    fun initFirstWallet() = appDatabase.walletDao.getFirstWallet()
}
```

MainActivityViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel()
{
    var currentWallet: LiveData<Wallet> = repository.initFirstWallet()
    
}
```

This is will work fine as intended without any threading issue.